# add data to listview from edittext another activity android

Tags: android, listview

i want to ask..

i have 2 activity, just say  form1 and form2, and i have a listview on form1. i want to add data from edittext in form2 with a button into listview in form 1..how can i do that?

if i use onResume() the user must change activity to form1 to get the listview refreshed..

i try to use this code but its seems didnt work..

```
if(form1.listviewname != null)
{
        ((ArrayAdapter)form1.listviewname.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}
```

thank you!!

------------------------------------------------------------edited----------

just now i tried to use this code on form2

```
list_list.add(myitem);
form1.listview.setAdapter(adapter1);                        
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

*myitem is string which get the value from textbox in form 2*

its seems work but now the problem is everytime i add the data to listview in form1 its always overwrite the existing data in listview..

how can i fix this?

thank you!!

RESOLVED---------------------------------------------------
resolved by declaring this on form2

```
public static ArrayList<String> list_list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

public static ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
```

i added public static.

thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-** Suppose `Activity` **A** has the `ListView` and `Activity` **B** has the `EditText` with `Button`.

**In Activity B :**

```
Button mbutt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_mSubmit);
EditText mtext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_mData);

mbutt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View v) {

                      Intent i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);

                      i.putExtra("text_key",mtext.getText().toString());

                      startActivity(i);
        }


});
```

**In Activity A :**

**-** Here in onResume(), do this

```
 Intent i = getIntent();

 String mdata = i.getExtras().getString("text_key");
```

**-** Now you have got the data in `mdata` variable, i hope you have used a `static ArrayList` in Activity A, to hold the data which in turn has to be fed into the `ArrayAdater`.

**Eg:**

```
public static ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**-** Now finally in the `onResume()`, you have to add this `mdata` variable's **value** into `ArrayList` and then fed it into the `ArrayAdpater` and then **again** set the `ListView` with this `Adapter`.